# Greasemonkey autoclick script cracked by site update

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

Would appreciate your help with something.

I have an autoclick Greasemonkey for Firefox script that autoclicks a link on the site I work at when a job comes in. The script is this:

```
var BEEP_URL = 'file:///C:/Users/Home/beep.html'; //local url to beep.html for     example 'file:///C:/deploy/html/beep.html'
var REFRESH_DELAY = 8; // in seconds
var CLICK_DELAY = 0; // in seconds
var LENGTH_MIN = 15 // min length of audio in minutes
var LENGTH_MAX = 600 // max length of audio in minutes 

function init() {
var refreshTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
}, REFRESH_DELAY * 1000);

if(!$('a:contains(Read now)').length){
    href = false;
    $('a:contains(Start)').each(function() {
        time = parseInt($(this).parents('td').nextAll('td').contents('small').html());
        if (!href && time >= LENGTH_MIN && time <= LENGTH_MAX) {
            GM_openInTab(BEEP_URL); 
            href = this.href;
            clearTimeout(refreshTimer);
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                top.location.href = href;
            }, CLICK_DELAY * 1000);
        }
    })
}
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
} else {
document.attachEvent('onload', init);
}
```

The important bits of the page on the site I work at looks like this:

```
<tr>
<td><a title = 'Job'>Job</a></td>

<td>4</td>

<td><i>Group</i></td>

<td>3/10/2011</td>

<td><a href=http://www.site.com>Start</a></td>

<td><a href='/sound/job_sound.mp3' ><img border=0 src=/images/audio.gif title='79 min uploaded 3/10/2011 7:39:31 AM' ></a><br /><small>80 min <br />7:39:31 AM</small></TD>

<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, the script refreshes the page and if a job comes in with the link 'Start' and the right amount of minutes for the `LENGTH_MIN` and `LENGTH_MAX` variables in the `small` tag in the table (second last `td` cell), then the script will click the 'Start' link.

Recently, however, the site has changed the structure of the page slightly so that it now looks like this:

```
<tr>
<td><a title = 'Job'>Job</a></td>

<td>4</td>

<td><i>Group</i></td>

<td>3/10/2011</td>

<td><a href=http://www.site.com>Start</a></td>

<td><small>Audio 1: </small><a href='/sound/job_sound.mp3' ><img border=0 src=/images/audio.gif title='Audio 1: 39 min uploaded 10/4/2011 7:13:06 AM' alt='Audio 1 39 min uploaded 10/4/2011 7:13:06 AM'></a><small>40 min 7:13:06 AM</small><BR><small>Audio 2: </small><a href='/audio/job_sound2.mp3' ><img border=0 src=/images/audio.gif title='Audio 2: 40 min uploaded 10/4/2011 7:15:19 AM' alt='Audio 2 40 min uploaded 10/4/2011 7:15:19 AM'></a><small>41 min 7:15:19 AM</small><br>&nbsp;<br></TD>

<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, the bit that the `LENGTH_MIN` and `LENGTH_MAX` variables is called by has been changed (at least, that's where I think the problem is) and now the script doesn't work anymore. Two or more audio files are shown now on the page and the time is inserted in the `small` tag. Is there anything you can see there that I can change in the script to get it to work with this page? It seems like it gets called by data in the page wrapped in `small` tags, and the site has changed how that section of the table is laid out which is causing the script problems. I'm not sure what to tweak in the script to make it still click the 'Start' link.

Would really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal change to fix this might be to replace `.contents('small')` (which, as far as I can tell from [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), probably doesn't do what you think anyway) with `.find('small').eq(1)`.  This might not be a very robust solution (i.e. it might break again in the future if there are more changes to the document structure), but it's hard to say what might be better without knowing more details.

Comment: Ilmari! This seems to be working :) I'm just going to test it a bit more, but this seems to really be working! Give me a second...

Comment: Okay, wow, I seriously think it's going to work. I haven't tested it on the site yet, just local, but it's working a treat local. I really appreciate it. Great stuff. Really great stuff. Sincerely appreciate your help.